# Excel formula to pull Top 5

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out how to pull the top (and bottom) five items sold for a particular group, but cannot figure it out.  Any suggestions?

Enter the person you want to check in the green box to populate the fields.

```
        PAUL        
JAKE            JOHN        
        STEVE       
        JAKE    

Salesman    Item     Amount             
PAUL    Blue     202        Top 5 Items sold    
PAUL    Orange   1,500          
PAUL    Green    28             
PAUL    Pink     62             
PAUL    Purple   10,215             
PAUL    Cherry   1,616          
PAUL    Soda     1,320          
PAUL    Tea  1,598      Bottom 5 Items Sold 
PAUL    Coffee   22             
PAUL    Pop  165            
PAUL    Grass    148            
PAUL    Weeds    3          
PAUL    Tar  147            
JOHN    Eyes     169            
JOHN    Teeth    1,258          
JOHN    Arm  1,247          
JOHN    Leg  1,396          
JOHN    Foot     13,598             
JOHN    Hand     12,458             
JOHN    Finger   12,477             
JOHN    Nailfile     1,036          
JOHN    Brush    4,567          
STEVE   Comb     8,901          
STEVE   Tweezer  2,345          
STEVE   Charger  3,456          
STEVE   Plate    4,567          
STEVE   Bowl     5,678          
STEVE   Cup  6,789          
STEVE   Spoon    7,890          
STEVE   Knife    8,902          
JAKE    Fork     8,998          
JAKE    Tongs    1,723          
JAKE    Spatula  9,856          
JAKE    Cookie Jar   1,616          
JAKE    cracker  2,589          
JAKE    Cake     1,628          
JAKE    Pie  528,116            
JAKE    Cupcake  5,286
```

Comment: based on what criteria?  The current top 5 cells with the salesman or the top 5 amounts of the salesman?  how are you looking for the output as well?  your question is a bit unclear....

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula, which assumes

- your data starts in the second row
- the persons name you are interested in is in D2
- all names are in column A
- all items are in column B
- all values are in column C
- you type the formula into cell E1 and drag it down from there

  ```
  {=MIN(IF(((LARGE(IF(($A$2:$A$22=$D$2),$C$2:$C$22),ROWS($A$2:A2)))=$C$2:$C$22)*(COUNTIFS($E$1:E1,$B$2:$B$22)=0),$B$2:$B$22))}
  ```

For the smallest values, replace LARGE with SMALL.

Answer (score 0):

Two Suggestions:

First, you could use two array formulas - see screenshot below. **Just remember to finish the formula with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`, otherwise the formula won't work.** You'll notice that Excel will automatically insert curly brackets around your formula `{}` signifying it is an array formula.  Do **NOT** type these.

1st Array formula to lookup the top `__` AMOUNT `Column G`

`=LARGE(IF($A$3:$A$40=$F$2,$C$3:$C$40,""),E5)`

2nd Array formula to lookup the ITEM name associate with the amount `Column F`

`=INDEX($B$3:$B$40,MATCH($F$2&$G5,($A$3:$A$40&$C$3:$C$40),0))`

Then, you can get fancy by adding in `data validation` like I have in `F2`.

[image: Array Formula x2]

**OR**

Second, you could create two PivotTables (top & bottom) like this:

1. Select Data > Insert > PivotTable
2. Layout Pivot Table like: Rows=Salesman, Item.  Values=Amount
3. Click the 'Row Labels' Filter button (1), Change field to `Item` (2), select Value Filters (3), Select Top 10 (4).
   [image: Steps]

**Finished product looks like this...**

[image: Top & Bottom 5 PivotTable]